# jquery: keep aspect ratio and contain div inside window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a div that will keep it's aspect ratio that maintains a with and height that will not exceed the screen's bounds.

This is the code that I have right now:

```
<div class="container"></div>

wW=$(window).width();
wH=$(window).height();
wHx=(wW/16)*9;
wWx=(wH/9)*16;
if(wW>wWx){
    vH1=$('.container').height();
    vW1=(vH1/9)*16;
    vP1=($(window).width()-vW1)*0.5;
    $('.container').css('width',vW1+'px');
    $('.container').css('left',vP1+'px');
    $('.container').css('height','100%');
    $('.container').css('top','0');
}
if(wH>wHx){
    vW2=$('.container').width();
    vH2=(vW2/16)*9;
    vP2=($(window).height()-vH2)*0.5;
    $('.container').css('height',vH2+'px');
    $('.container').css('top',vP2+'px');
    $('.container').css('width','100%');
    $('.container').css('left','0');
}
```

It almost works as intended but it fails in some random situations and the page needs to be refreshed to fix the problem.

Edit: the same function is executed on resize (it fails in some random cases during resize):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    .........
});
```

Edit2: The script fails, after manually resizing the window and then clicking the minimize/maximize button of the browser. I've got the same results with Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help

```
// HTML
<div class="container"></div>

// CSS (SASS)
.container {
  background: red;
  max-width: 100%;

  &:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    // for 16/9 this is the height you need
    padding-top: 56.25%;

  }
}

// JavaScript
$(function(){
  $(window).resize(function(){
    var width  = $(window).width(),
        height = $(window).height();

    if (width/height > 16/9) {
      $('.container').css('max-width', height * 16 / 9);
    } else {
      $('.container').css('max-width', '100%');
    }
  })
  // trigger resize so it takes the
  // right size on load
  .trigger('resize');

});
```

examle http://codepen.io/istavros/full/vxwVoW/

Comment: Yes but I want to contain the div inside the visible window.This CSS approach keeps the aspect ratio but does not keep the div contained in the visible window.

Comment: Updated my answer. Adding a little javascript you can maintain the ratio when the ratio of the window is greater than 16/9

Comment: If this answer helped you could you please accept it as the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
<div class="container"></div>
//CSS
.container {
max-width: 100vw;
max-height: 100vh;
}
```